# Why create custom activity for sequential workflow in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, android-activity, workflow, task

I created a custom activity according to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh128696%28v=office.14%29.aspx). My test project worked but can anyone explain the reason for creating custom activity? Is it because replicators cannot contain more than one activity?